# Background image size on iPhone

Tags: ios, background-image, skspritenode

Hello I have made a background image (size: 1136 x 650). Then I have implemented it into my app but on iPhone 5 it is too small though in all the guides I read they said that 1136x650 would be the size for a background image on iPhone 5. Then I have used the same image but with size: 2272x1300 (@2x) and now it fits perfectly.

Does that mean that I have to use a background image with the size: 2208x1242(normal) and 6624x3726 (@3x) for an iPhone 6+?

Comment: Are you doing this in interface builder? If so, does it look ok in interface builder? You might need to change the content mode on the image view. Using a 1136x650 image on a 5S should fill the screen if you've done everything properly.

Comment: No I have added everything programmatically but now I use a one color background in form of an SKShapeNode which looks much better than the background I've used before!

Comment: Make sure the content mode is set to aspect fill, I think its stretch to fit by default. (Also, the 5S's screen is 1136 x 640, not 650)

Comment: I've used the following code:

var exampleNode = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height)

Comment: If you want to make an image, you need to use UIImageView. UIImageView has a property called contentMode, play around with different values of that, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The number of physical pixels in the screen and the number of points in the screen's coordinate system are different numbers. As you have discovered an iPhone 5 has four times as many physical pixels on the screen as logical pixels.

For iPhone 6, in order to fill the whole screen in landscape orientation, you would need a 1334 x 750 image. For the 6+, you would need a 2208 x 1242 image. A quick way to tell is to check the requirements for the launch image, which you can get to from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2).